# Is -didReceiveMemoryWarning useful anymore if I am using ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

When I create a new subclass of `UIViewController` in Xcode, it comes with default methods such as `init` and `viewDidLoad`. The last one though, is `didReceiveMemoryWarning`. This made me think, if I am using ARC, should I worry about this? Here is the default method.

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

The keyword here is dispose. Since I cannot explicitly call `release` on any objects while using ARC, should I even implement this method?

Comment: It is! There's a large difference between an NSArray with 1000 objects and with 0 objects, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Using ARC or MRC makes no difference. Either way your app could get memory warnings. Use the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` to clean up any memory that you can such as emptying caches or whatnot.

You can still cleanup objects under ARC so they are deallocated. You just need to remove all references to the object(s).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should implement it, even if you simply leave it "as is". Just by calling `[super didReceiveMemoryWarning]` you allow your app to clean up memory in low memory conditions (which may be caused by something else than your app), such as release cached images (loaded via imageNamed or Storyboard, for example) or views that are not currently visible.

A good article: [Managing Memory Level Warnings](http://learn-iphone-programming-by-example.blogspot.com/2013/05/managing-memory-level-warning-best.html)

Comment: Implementing the method just to call `[super didReceiveMemoryWarning]` is really the same as not implementing it at all.